# Unexpected end of file error - removing function fixes issue

Tags: php, syntax-error

Ok, I have looked over and over this code but I can't seem to find the problem and why I am getting this error, here is the end of the file:

```
function ouputMainSlider() {

    global $USER;

    // Get details
    $query = "SELECT id, bigimage, heading, fullarticle, dateadded FROM news WHERE status = 1 ";
    $query .= "AND (state = '" . $USER->state . "' OR state = 'ALL') AND newstype != 1 and bigimage != '' ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY dateadded DESC LIMIT 10";
    $restresult = mysql_query($query);

    while ($restaurant = mysql_fetch_array($restresult)) :

        // Trim article for preview
        $preview = trim_str($restaurant['fullarticle'], 270);

        ?>

        <li>

            <img alt="<?=fixup($restaurant['heading'])?>" src="images/frontpage/<?=$restaurant['bigimage']?>" width="615" height="309" />
            <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>
            <p>         
                <strong><a href="#"><?=fixup($restaurant['heading'])?></a></strong>
                <em><?=fixup($preview)?></em>               
            </p>

        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

}

?>
```

If I take out that function the problem goes away.

Comment: A strategy for debugging parse errors is to strategically comment/delete bits of code until you find the problem.

Comment: I think that space between the closing parenthesis and the colon on your while might be the culprit. ETA: I was about to add to that there is one too many `?>` tags but I see it's been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to your `<?php endwhile; ?>`, which closes `?>` before closing the function's `}`, without re-opeining `<?php`. Since there is no subsequent code inside `<?php ?>`, the PHP parser sees the remaining stuff outside as plain text output and assumes you have no properly closed the `}`. It happens that that is the end of the file, and so that is how the error is reported.

```
while ($restaurant = mysql_fetch_array($restresult)) :

        // Trim article for preview
        $preview = trim_str($restaurant['fullarticle'], 270);

        ?>

        <li>

            <img alt="<?=fixup($restaurant['heading'])?>" src="images/frontpage/<?=$restaurant['bigimage']?>" width="615" height="309" />
            <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>
            <p>         
                <strong><a href="#"><?=fixup($restaurant['heading'])?></a></strong>
                <em><?=fixup($preview)?></em>               
            </p>

        </li>

    <?php
     endwhile; // Don't close ?> here!
```

The `while: / endwhile` syntax is useful for templating where you are *primarily* mixing HTML with PHP code, but can be confusing when used inside a function like this, as you lose the visual cues provided by open and closed `{}` groups. I kind of recommend against mixing the syntax in this way.

Really, I would recommend against ever closing and reopening `<?php ?>` inside a function, but that is a matter of style. Instead, construct the strings that a function outputs and `echo` or `return` them.

```
function ouputMainSlider() {
    global $USER;

    // Get details
    $query = "SELECT id, bigimage, heading, fullarticle, dateadded FROM news WHERE status = 1 ";
    $query .= "AND (state = '" . $USER->state . "' OR state = 'ALL') AND newstype != 1 and bigimage != '' ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY dateadded DESC LIMIT 10";
    $restresult = mysql_query($query);

    $html = "";
    while ($restaurant = mysql_fetch_array($restresult)) {
        // Trim article for preview 
        // You can't call functions in the HEREDOC, so call them here first
        $preview = fixup(trim_str($restaurant['fullarticle'], 270));
        $heading = fixup($restaurant['heading']);

        // Build the string with a HEREDOC, insead of directly sending it to the output buffer
        // by closing ?> and reopening <?php
        $html .=<<<HTMLSTRING
        <li>
            <img alt="$heading" src="images/frontpage/{$restaurant['bigimage']}" width="615" height="309" />
            <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>
            <p>         
                <strong><a href="#">$heading</a></strong>
                <em>$preview</em>               
            </p>
        </li>
HTMLSTRING;
// No whitespace before the closing of the HEREDOC!
    }
    // Then echo the HTML output
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Haha good spotting of the missing opening tag! :) I've recently started using syntax like `while: / endwhile` a lot more because it's far easier to connect the end parts then it is with just braces; but I agree, in this instance it's not really needed. :) Thanks for the other tips too!

Comment: One question..... shouldn't that be `$html .=<<<HTMLSTRING` so it grabs the data of EACH entry?